# When I uncommit a PBI, how do I define the default product backlog iteration for it in TFS?

Tags: tfs, backlog

We are using TFS 2013. Now and then we need to move a PBI from a sprint backlog to the product backlog. The usual reasons are for an erroneous commitment, or it is an unfinished story which needs to be postponed, not carried forward.

Our problem is that when we drag the PBI back to the product backlog, the iteration is set to "X" when we want it to be set to our current release path, "X/V1". All of our sprint iteration paths are "X/V1/SPRINTS/nn".

(I checked the answers to [How to UnCommit to a PBI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390471/how-to-uncommit-to-a-pbi/22391670#22391670), but they are ultimately not relevant to the issue of the resulting iteration path.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the backlog iteration for the team to X/V1 (via the admin pages) you should find that dragging a PBI from the sprint backlog to the product backlog sets the iteration path as expected.

[image]

Be aware that setting the backlog iteration also automatically filters the backlog view to only show PBIs under the X/V1 path. If you then want to see other product backlog items (i.e. those under the X or X/V2 paths, etc) you would need to use work item queries.

Comment: When you start Release 2 you'd have to update the Team's Backlog iteration.

Comment: To also have a cross-release view, you could create a 2nd team that uses the root as backlog iteration and (optionally) the releases as active sprints.

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks. The UI with the hidden triangle seems to be a bad design. I didn't know to look there.